# Read the system log on Android 4.1

Tags: android

Now , I want to read the system log on android 4.1 . But just can  only get the application itself log . My code as following:

```
Process logcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "logcat","ActivityManager:V","*:S" });
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcatProc.getInputStream()));  
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.e("log",line);
}
```

it Seems can work on android 4.0 or previous version. anybody have tried this ? Or i need the root permission ?

Answer (score 5):

System logs changed in 4.1 and are now accessible only by system apps. (Source: [Google I/O Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WDDgoxvQsrQ#t=1369s).) This is an exception on rooted devices, of course, if the installed app is set to be a system app.

Aside from this, there is no way to access the system logs on Android 4.1+. *Note: End users can access the system log by using the (very finicky) shortcut of <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Vol Up</kbd> + <kbd>Vol Down</kbd>.*

Comment: Maverick bravo, not an Andriod developer but just happened to come across this. Who would have known this.. :|

Comment: @ChinBoon Amen! I wouldn't have known if I hadn't needed to find the system log about a week ago.

Comment: thank you , @Eric . the same to you, we need to analyze the system log in our app , then find this .

Comment: @Kris.lee Yeah, I'm afraid you're out of luck in that regard. Non-system apps *cannot* read the system log.